# How can I map ":vsplit ." to <F7> in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'd like to create a mapping for `:vsplit .`.

I tried adding this to `.vimrc`...

```
nmap <F7> verticalsplit .
```

However, when I hit `<F7>` it goes into insert mode and inserts "`calsplit .tttt`". (Why "tttt"?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put a `:` before it and a `<CR>` after.

```
nmap <F7> :vsplit .<CR>
```

`nmap` starts in normal mode so you have to give it exactly what you'd type.

You get "tttt" because your mapping was typing `v` (to go into Visual mode), `e` (jump to the end of a word), `r` (go into replace-mode), `t` (type a t and replace whatever is visually selected with `t`s).